# Trying to build a table with diferent columns per row

Tags: tables

I'm trying to build a table like this [image]

this is my code

```
\begin{tabular}{ |c c|}
\tabheadformat
\tabhead{HISTORIA DE USUARIO} \\
\hline
\textbf{Número:} &  \textbf{Usuario:}\\
\hline
\textbf{Nombre Historia:} \\
\hline
\textbf{Prioridad en negocio:}  & \textbf{Riesgo en desarrollo:} \\
\hline
\textbf{Esfuerzo:} & \textbf{Sprint asignado:} \\
\hline
\textbf{Programador responsable:}  \\
\hline
\textbf{Descripción:}  \\
\hline
\textbf{Validación:} \\   
\hline
\end{tabular}
```

If someone can help, I'm very new with Latex. The only diference with the example is the title must be centered.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. Where and how are `\tabhead` and `\tabheadformat` defined?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

[image: example]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\caption{My caption}
\label{my-label}
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|}
\hline
\multicolumn{3}{|r|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}HISTORIA DE USUARIO}             \\ \hline
Número:                  & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{Usuario:}                      \\ \hline
\multicolumn{3}{|l|}{Nombre Historia:}                                        \\ \hline
\multicolumn{2}{|l|}{Prioridad en negocio:} & Riesgo en desarrollo:           \\ \hline
\multicolumn{2}{|l|}{Esfuerzo:}             & Sprint asignado:                \\ \hline
\multicolumn{3}{|l|}{Programador responsable:}                                \\ \hline
\multicolumn{3}{|l|}{Descripción:}                                            \\ \hline
\multicolumn{3}{|l|}{Validación:}                                             \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @Aytaz You could apply bold and complete the table by yourself. I think that you are more interested in the layout of the table.